# Language Specific layout for android

Tags: android, android-layout

I know that we can display multiple languages support for our android application with different 
values folder  example values-en , values-ar.

My question is can we change our layout style when there is change of language.

As in English every thing starts form "left -to right"  however Arabic is just apposite of it .
so is it possible to place a image on left when language selected is English and Change the layout when language changes to Arabic

Comment: you can make the folder like `layout-ar`

Comment: @MMohsinNaeem thanks buddy. right now i am having a LG-P715 Phone  with 4.1.2 but it do not show Arabic language how to add that language in my mobile to get Arabic keyboard and test Arabic language layout

Comment: Set `android:layout_gravity` and `android:gravity` to RIGHT.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The layout direction of your application. `ldrtl` means `"layout-direction-right-to-left"`. `ldltr` means `"layout-direction-left-to-right"` and is the default implicit value.

This can apply to any resource such as `layouts, drawables`, or `values`.

For example, if you want to provide some specific layout for the `Arabic language` and some generic layout for any other "right-to-left" language (like Persian or Hebrew) then you would have:

```
res/
layout/   
    main.xml  (Default layout)
layout-ar/  
    main.xml  (Specific layout for Arabic)
layout-ldrtl/  
    main.xml  (Any "right-to-left" language, except
              for Arabic, because the "ar" language qualifier
              has a higher precedence.)
```

**Note:** To enable `right-to-left` layout features for your app, you must set `supportsRtl` to `"true"` and `set targetSdkVersion to 17 or higher.`

Answer (score 2):

> can we change our layout style when there is change of language.

Yes. You can provide different layouts according to the language user chooses. This is clearly described in the [**Providing Resources**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html) documentation.

Infact a specific layout qualifier is provided for supporting right-to-left-directed languages called [`res/layout-ldrtl`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#table2).

P.S: This attribute is only supported from API 17.

Answer (score 0):

[Add direction- and language-specific resources](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages#MirroringAddResources)

This step involves adding specific versions of your layout, drawables, and values resource files that contain customized values for different languages and text directions.

In Android 4.2 (API level 17) and higher, you can use the -ldrtl (layout-direction-right-to-left) and -ldltr (layout-direction-left-to-right) resource qualifiers. To maintain backward compatibility with loading existing resources, older versions of Android use a resource's language qualifiers to infer the correct text direction.

Suppose that you want to add a specific layout file to support RTL scripts, such as the Hebrew, Arabic, and Persian languages. To do this, you add a layout-ldrtl/ directory in your res/ directory, as shown in the following example:

```
res/
    layout/
        main.xml //This layout file is loaded by default.
    layout-ldrtl/
        main.xml //This layout file is loaded for languages using an
                 //RTL text direction, including Arabic, Persian, and Hebrew.
```

If you want to add a specific version of the layout that is designed for only Arabic text, your directory structure becomes the following:

```
res/
    layout/
        main.xml //This layout file is loaded by default.
    layout-ar/
        main.xml //This layout file is loaded for Arabic text.
    layout-ldrtl/
        main.xml //This layout file is loaded only for non-Arabic
                 //languages that use an RTL text direction.
```

**Note:** Language-specific resources take precedence over layout-direction-specific resources, which take precedence over the default resources.