# android: design code to dynamicaly select layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, dynamic, view

I want the same application to be delivered 2 different set of layouts. Ie the functionality is same but the graphics will be different for two different versions of the app. So i want to keep the same code and based of some variables want to decide which layout to be set for each activity. SO for each activity i will define two different layout.

This is my requirement. What is the best way to implement this. I can have an if else in each activity and define which layout to be set. Is that the right and best way. Please  give your options on this

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this answer. It's about accessing a resource file from identifier, ie file name. You can do this with any type of resource (I think).

[How to use getResource.getIdentifier() to get Layout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17203454/how-to-use-getresource-getidentifier-to-get-layout)

Basically, you can do an if-else statement and assign the id of the layout you wish to use to a variable then load the layout using the identifier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there are many ways for ex you can change your layout based upon the orientation i.e landscape or portrait or you can change your layouts using languages for ex- you can create various folders for different languages.

Please explain your requirement briefly and if possible post some code also.

You can follow below links also.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

[Language Specific layout for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18628258/language-specific-layout-for-android)

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e8478/supporting-different-languages-layouts-in-an-android-appli/